# How is the wattage of a human larynx calculated?

Tags: acoustics, power, biology

This [site](http://www.ncvs.org/ncvs/tutorials/voiceprod/tutorial/q&a.html) says the typical human voice has a wattage of about 1W. Another [site](http://www.physicscentral.com/explore/poster-coffee.cfm) indicates it is 80db with about 0.001W of energy.

I'm confused. 
How does one compare 80db of 0.001W against 1W? 
Most importantly how is the wattage of the human larynx calculated?

Answer (score 1):

The 1W in the first site seems to be referring to the total *transmitted* vocal power.  The 0.001W in the other site sounds like it's referring to the *received* power at a point near the vocal source.  The power received in practice would depend on:

1. The power transmitted by the source;
2. The distance from this source;
3. Some measure of the efficiency of the receiver.

There are many different decibel acoustic [measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Acoustics_2).  It's hard to tell from those sites exactly which one they're using.  If its the *sound power level* measure, then 80dB gives the power ratio relative to $10^{-12}W$, which would actually give 0.0001W, not 0.001W so maybe a typo?

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas on the the latter question - how is the wattage of the larynx calculated?

Comment: Not really, but perhaps I'd try putting someone in an anechoic chamber, and placing a sound level meter at a bunch of sample points maybe 1m from the head, then integrating the results.

Answer (score 0):

The larynx will be able to produce a very wide range of powers (ranging from a whisper to a scream). To estimate the power output, all you need is a decibel meter and a ruler.

For example, a person speaking normally produces a sound of around 60dB at 1m from the source. This works out to an intensity of 10^-6 W/m^2. Assuming the sound power is spread evenly across a spherical sound wave, we find a power output of 1.25 x 10^-5 Watts.